# button background colour overlaps flexbox container

Tags: html, css, button, background, flexbox

I  have created a button inside a flex box at the bottom. When i go to inspect element I can see that the background colour overlaps the flex container as i had increased the height of the background colour of the button.  so, how can I move this so that the background colour no longer overlaps the flex box? this is only visible when using inspect element but annoying.

Comment: Please publish some code that demonstrates your effort to solve the problem and gives others an idea how exactly you're trying to solve it.  This assumes html, JavaScript, CSS and whatever other relevant code you have.

Comment: .flex a { color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#5385c1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 16px 30px; }

Comment: when i add padding to the button to obtain the background color height of the button , it overlaps the margin of the paragraph above it. The overlapping is only visible when you inspect the element.do i need to add more space between the p and a ?element?

Comment: It may depend on your `z-index` css property - try set it lower for one element and smaller for the other.